# Is there any solution for enter presses?

Tags: javascript, input, enter

Well, I was trying for an event listener `onkeypress` for adding my data to the to-do list, but when press enter it naturally refreshes the page and it doesn't add to it.

Otherwise, I added `e.preventDefault();` also but it again refreshes its page not add it

```
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event){
  if(event.keyCode === 13){
`its refreshes the when I press enter`
    addToDo ("drink coffee");
  }
});
```

An alternative solution I came up with for refreshing

```
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event){
event.preventDefault();
  if(event.keyCode === 13){
    addToDo ("drink coffee");
  }
});
```

Can I have any alternative solution for this???

Comment: Are you using form ?

Comment: yes, I am using form

Comment: I think you should try to prevent the form from being submitted
try this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350247/how-to-prevent-form-from-being-submitted) and sorry for the late response

Comment: Can you share your html as well? is this listener for the form only? or for the whole page?

Comment: my html body tag

Comment: <section class="toDO">
    <div class="header">
      <h1 class="title">TODO</h1>
      <i class="title_cta" onClick="myFunction()"></i>
    </div>
    <form class="form_in">
      <span class="circle"></span>
     <input type="text" id = "myInput" placeholder="Your ToDo's" class="todo_input"/>
    </form>
    <div class="activities">
      <ul class="list"></ul>
    </div>
    </section>

Comment: no problem @Danial appreriate for helping me